# gethostbyaddr and checkdnsrr are not giving any output

Tags: php, linux, dns

I am running a php script that returns DNS server address and I am using following code for it.

```
echo $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
print_r (checkdnsrr ($hostname));
```

My server is Linux based. Why is this not returning anything?

Comment: You will not always get a hostname for an address.

Comment: Downvoted for the nondescript title, would you consider amending? I will undownvote if you do. Meaningful titles for newsgroups and forums have been part of netiquette for thirty or so years `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You code is working Ok when I run it on my server.

The problem must be somewhere in your system! 
It is possible that:

- you are behind a NAT
- have not a reverse DNS lookup for your IP.

Comment: how can i check the above conditions and how can enable them ?

Answer (score 1):

Add more debug output (or use a [debugger](http://docs.php.net/debugger)) to find out...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]=', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "<br />\n";
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo '$hostname=', $hostname, "<br />\n";
$result = checkdnsrr($hostname);
var_dump($result);
echo "<br />\ndone.";
```

Comment: If needed use var_dump() everywhere instead of echo

Comment: i ran ur code and got this - bool(false)
done. iam a newbie so dont know what this means?